# sorting arrows in gridview not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have gridview defined as below

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyDataGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="4"  GridLines="None"  
     AutoGenerateColumns="False"  EmptyDataText="No records found" AllowSorting="True"  
     AllowPaging="True" PageSize="2"
     OnPageIndexChanging="MyDataGridView_OnPageIndexChanging" OnSorting="MyDataGridView_OnSorting" OnRowDataBound="MyDataGridView_OnRowDataBound">
     <Columns>
           <asp:BoundField DataField="CreatedDate" HeaderText="CreatedDate" SortExpression="CreatedDate" />
           <asp:BoundField DataField="NameOfCity" HeaderText="Cityname"   />

     </Columns>
 </asp:GridView>
```

Then in my rowbound event i wrote below code

```
protected void MyDataGridView_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        string imgAsc = @" <img src='../Images/asc.gif' border='0' title='Ascending' />";
        string imgDes = @" <img src='../Images/desc.gif' border='0' title='Descendng' />";
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
        {
            foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
            {
                LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)cell.Controls[0];
                if (lnkbtn.Text == MyDataGridView.SortExpression)
                {
                    if (DataGridView.SortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
                    {
                        lnkbtn.Text += imgAsc;
                    }
                    else
                        lnkbtn.Text += imgDes;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But when code runs then i get error "Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index"

When i debug i see that i get this error inside foreach loop when it comes inside second time.
Its on the line `LinkButton lnkbtn = (LinkButton)cell.Controls[0];`

Even if i move cursor forward and skip error i am still not able to see up down arrows. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You're misssing `SortExpression` in `NameOfCity` data field

Comment: @mhmtztmr i dont need sorting for Nameofcity

Answer (score 0):

FYI your tag above looks incorrect: PageSize=" is incomplete. Secondly, do you really want to add a link button's text as the image tag? This doesn't seem right (usually you'd set an ImageUrl)

There's a different approach. As per http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scothu/archive/2010/08/28/gridview-with-sort-arrows-and-showing-header-when-empty.aspx
you can define some templates

```
<SortedAscendingHeaderStyle /> 
<SortedDescendingHeaderStyle /> 
<SortedAscendingCellStyle /> 
<SortedDescendingCellStyle />
```

and in turn specify custom css styles

```
  <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" DataSourceID="EntityDataSource1" PageSize="5">
        <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortasc" />
       <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle CssClass="sortdesc" />
  </asp:GridView>
```

Styles

```
th.sortasc a  
{
    display:block; padding:0 4px 0 15px; 
    background:url(img/asc.gif) no-repeat;  
}

th.sortdesc a 
{
    display:block; padding:0 4px 0 15px; 
    background:url(img/desc.gif) no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Dont we need to add columns?

Comment: That article I posted has a basic code example with css (the aspx though is the same as above. I'll edit to add styles too